# How to add custom term in wordpress post slug?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to build an URL in WordPress site with a pattern which looks like this:

```
mydomain.com/[category-name]/[slug]/[photo-{0-9}]/
```

Tried re-writing URLs and added "photo" param to query var to catch the photo number, but couldn't succeed.
Am already using a plugin to remove /category/ from URLs.

Any idea to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you just want to remove category name from url

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
yourdomain.com/%category%/%postname%/photo-%post_id%/
```

it is not clear that what are [slug] and {0-9} are. But I think you can manage with them with this answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. To be clear, by [slug] I meant the %postname%, and [photo-{0-9}]: it can be photo-01, photo-02 etc for a single post. I use a plugin to save gallery images of a post. Requirement is when %photo-3% is the request URL, 3rd image of gallery will need to be loaded. Am not sure how to detect %photo-[num]% in WP rewrite rule

Comment: would it be ok to use %photo-[name]% and then you can name your gallery images like 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc ?

Comment: Yes, that could do. I want to catch this %photo-[name]% in the request and add it to query var, the rest i should be able to do!

Comment: try the answer on this   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61749/adding-meta-values-to-permalink

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this working
Adding the solution here so someone can make use or tune it further

I did this adding following rewrite key value pair to `$wp_rewrite->rules` array:

```
'([^)]+)/([^)]+)/(photo-\d+)?$' => 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]&photo=$matches[3]'
```

This regex groups (inside parenthesis()) url to $matches array which is turn assigned to WP query string.